# Cloning a Git repo into a new repo - without commit history

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket

So I'm trying to get my head around Git, and have the need (why I have this need I won't go into) to be able to take the files from one repo, via command line, and put them into a brand new repository WITHOUT taking all of the previous commit history with it.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is `git init` to create a new repository, and then grab the files from my existing repo, either using clone or subtree (I've not got my head fully around this yet so may be barking up the wrong tree), and then add, commit, and then push these to my new repository.

```
git init
--- get the files from stock repo ---
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin <url of my new repo>
git push -u origin master
```

My repositories are all on Bitbucket, if that makes a difference,

Comment: Can you not just rsync the files somewhere else and then `git init` there?

Comment: yeah, it looks unprofessional if there are too many swear words and such in a repo :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can clone the old repository like:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/repository.git
```

and then you delete the git directory:

```
rm -rf .git/
```

Now you create the new repository:

```
git init
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have those files from stock repo cloned somewhere, you can do a:

```
cd yourNewRepo
git --work-tree=/path/to/stock/repo add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

That means: you are considering the files from `/path/to/stock/repo` as your working tree for your new repo (just for the `git add` step)

Once the index of your new repo has recorded those files, you can forget about the stock repo, and commit those new files (without any prior history) in your new repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got the TMI repo cloned you can reset your clone's master to have only that one's tip commit for history with

```
git branch -f master `git commit-tree -m "My new initial commit" origin/master^{tree}`
```

and then do as usual, fix up the remotes and push histories around as as you like.

(**edit**: if you've got master checked out `git branch` won't want to rewrite the ref, but you're not touching the content at all, so you can bypass all the porcelain's handholding and just do it

```
git update-ref -m "Truncating history" refs/heads/master \
        `git commit-tree -m "My new initial commit" origin/master^{tree}`
```

)

Answer (score 1):

1. You clone the old repository like:

   `git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/repository.git`
2. Then you delete the git directory:

   `rm -rf .git`
3. Create the new repository:

   `git init`
4. Commit the new repository and push it to the master origin

   `git push -u origin master`

If possibele, check the status of the git log to verify you have the correct info logged.

Comment: `rm -rf` works better than `rm -R` in the accepted answer

Comment: Why even resurrect this old question?